# What can we do to help bring more attention and users to the SO site?

Tags: feature-request

I have noticed that Stackoverflow in general doesn't have a solid base for tech support questions such as the hardware site, and the site is still in beta and to my knowledge it has been for a while. Are there ways to promote the site or ways to bring more people into the stack?

I apologize if this question isn't suitable. I am still new and learning so don't be afraid to correct me. I am just trying to promote things that I enjoy doing and it seems most sites on the SO are for DevOps or most things developer related which is awesome but I think we should incorporate other ways to draw attention to sites that aren't getting traction.